# 3d анимация. При наведении на все, кроме основного блока, ломается эффект

Tags: javascript, css

Для примера поставил два блока, чтобы вы увидели, как анимация должна работать и как она работает.

Левый блок работает отлично: в зависимости от того, откуда наводят мышью, соответственно от этой стороны срабатывает эффект.

В правой стороне есть *svg*-иконка, которая при наведении выходит поверх синего окна.

Если навести, не задевая иконку или текст, можно и не заметить глюк. Но если навести сразу на *svg*-иконку, то глюк сразу можно увидеть. Немного "поигравшись" указателем внутри *svg*-иконки, не выходя из рамки *svg*, можно легко заметить проблему.

Ссылка: [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/KxwYqY) .

Я считаю, что тут проблема в **css**

Мои попытки:

**1**. Пытался дать `position absolute` этому блоку, но тогда все ломалось, и глюк также был

**2**. Пытался убрать `display block` из класса `icon-close`. Это не сработало тоже

И много других манипуляций с **CSS**, но ничего не помогло.

Очень прошу помогите.

```js
var nodes  = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
    _nodes = [].slice.call(nodes, 0);

var getDirection = function (ev, obj) {
    var w = obj.offsetWidth,
        h = obj.offsetHeight,
        x = (ev.pageX - obj.offsetLeft - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
        y = (ev.pageY - obj.offsetTop - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
        d = Math.round( Math.atan2(y, x) / 1.57079633 + 5 ) % 4;
  
    return d;
};

var addClass = function ( ev, obj, state ) {
    var direction = getDirection( ev, obj ),
        class_suffix = "";
    
    obj.className = "";
    
    switch ( direction ) {
        case 0 : class_suffix = '-top';    break;
        case 1 : class_suffix = '-right';  break;
        case 2 : class_suffix = '-bottom'; break;
        case 3 : class_suffix = '-left';   break;
    }
    
    obj.classList.add( state + class_suffix );
};

// bind events
_nodes.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function (ev) {
        addClass( ev, this, 'in' );
    }, false);

    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function (ev) {
        addClass( ev, this, 'out' );
    }, false);
});
```

```css
.icon-close {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-close svg {
  margin-top: calc(70% / 2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.txt {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  line-height: 1;
}

.container-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.container-inner ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container-inner ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.container-inner ul li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 18, 156, 0.9);
  -webkit-perspective: 540px;
  perspective: 540px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: 290px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container-inner ul li:hover svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.container-inner ul li:hover svg path {
  fill: white;
}
.container-inner ul li:hover .txt {
  color: white;
}
.container-inner ul li .info {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(26, 88, 156, 0.9);
}
.container-inner ul li .info p {
  color: #fff;
}

.in-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes in-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes in-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes in-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes in-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes in-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes in-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes in-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@keyframes out-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@keyframes out-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@keyframes out-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
@keyframes out-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container-inner'>
   <ul class="blue">
      <li>
         <div class='info'>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et 
               malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
               feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
               Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>   
         </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
         <a class="box" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <span class="icon-close">
               <svg width="57" height="57" viewBox="0 0 57 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <path d="M53.7612 30.9051L53.7153 25.2484L31.0887 25.432L30.905 2.80538L25.2483 2.85129L25.432 25.478L2.80532 25.6616L2.85123 31.3183L25.4779 31.1346L25.6616 53.7613L31.3182 53.7154L31.1346 31.0887L53.7612 30.9051Z" fill="#3116F8"/>
               </svg>
            </span>
            <span class="txt">contact <br> us &bull;</span>
            <div class='info standard'>

            </div>
           </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я считаю, что тут проблема в css

тут проблема в том, что `mouseover` и `mouseout` срабатывает на дочернем элементе

---

### `mouseout`

UPD: **НЕ**
берём немного магии отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698240/4794368
т.к. при динамическом добавлении/удалении элементов могут возникнуть проблемы

лучше сделать так

```
el.addEventListener('mouseout', function (ev) {
    if (ev.currentTarget.contains(ev.relatedTarget))return;
}, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

ev.relatedTarget - куда ушла мышь
ev.currentTarget - нода, которая подписана на событие (el)
node.contains( otherNode ) - Возвращает `true` если `otherNode` является потомком `node`, или непосредственно самим node. В противном случае возвращает `false`.

### `mouseover`

чуть-чуть пишем сами

```
let qwa = false
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function (ev) {
    if(qwa)return;
    qwa=!qwa
}, false);
el.addEventListener('mouseout', function (ev) {
    qwa=!qwa
}, false);
```

### результат

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  _nodes = [].slice.call(nodes, 0);

var getDirection = function(ev, obj) {
  var w = obj.offsetWidth,
    h = obj.offsetHeight,
    x = (ev.pageX - obj.offsetLeft - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
    y = (ev.pageY - obj.offsetTop - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
    d = Math.round(Math.atan2(y, x) / 1.57079633 + 5) % 4;

  return d;
};

var addClass = function(ev, obj, state) {
  var direction = getDirection(ev, obj),
    class_suffix = "";

  obj.className = "";

  switch (direction) {
    case 0:
      class_suffix = '-top';
      break;
    case 1:
      class_suffix = '-right';
      break;
    case 2:
      class_suffix = '-bottom';
      break;
    case 3:
      class_suffix = '-left';
      break;
  }

  obj.classList.add(state + class_suffix);
};

// bind events
_nodes.forEach(function(el) {
  let qwa = false
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
    if (qwa) return;
    qwa = !qwa
    addClass(ev, this, 'in');
  }, false);

  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(ev) {
    if (ev.currentTarget.contains(ev.relatedTarget)) return;
    qwa = !qwa
    addClass(ev, this, 'out');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.icon-close {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-close svg {
  margin-top: calc(70% / 2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.txt {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  line-height: 1;
}

.container-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-inner ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-inner ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container-inner ul li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 18, 156, 0.9);
  -webkit-perspective: 540px;
  perspective: 540px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: 290px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-inner ul li:hover svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.container-inner ul li:hover svg path {
  fill: white;
}

.container-inner ul li:hover .txt {
  color: white;
}

.container-inner ul li .info {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(26, 88, 156, 0.9);
}

.container-inner ul li .info p {
  color: #fff;
}

.in-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes in-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes in-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes in-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes in-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes in-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes in-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes in-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@keyframes out-top {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@keyframes out-right {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@keyframes out-bottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}

@keyframes out-left {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 104deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container-inner'>
  <ul class="blue">
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="box" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="icon-close">
               <svg width="57" height="57" viewBox="0 0 57 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="black" fill-opacity="0" transform="translate(28.0537) rotate(44.535)"/>
                  <path d="M53.7612 30.9051L53.7153 25.2484L31.0887 25.432L30.905 2.80538L25.2483 2.85129L25.432 25.478L2.80532 25.6616L2.85123 31.3183L25.4779 31.1346L25.6616 53.7613L31.3182 53.7154L31.1346 31.0887L53.7612 30.9051Z" fill="#3116F8"/>
               </svg>
            </span>
        <span class="txt">contact <br> us &bull;</span>
        <div class='info standard'>

        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: как ты это сделал сверхмозг O_o

Comment: Если бы было обьяснения коду было бы отлично потому что я ничего не понял что тваритсья в функции traversechildren и в цикле nodes.foreach также что за магический оператор __!!~__

Comment: можно просто заменить `!!~list.indexOf(e)` на `-1 !==list.indexOf(e)`; `!!` - привести к булевому;  `~-1` === `0`; `!!0` === `false`; `traverseChildren` - судя по всему возвращает массив потомков.

Comment: @Demon__ANT, тк часть про `mouseout` сам нагуглил - поэтому и говорю ©берём немного магии отсюда

Comment: спасибо огромное плюсанул

Comment: @Demon__ANT, обновил ответ. не нравится мне `let list = traverseChildren(el);` лучше сделать так `if (ev.currentTarget.contains(ev.relatedTarget))return;` и в случае чего нагуглить полифилл на `contains`

Comment: а мне нравилсья старый вариант он был сложным.Я его изучаю :)